# Andengine how to update mask bit of a body at runtime

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-physics, physics-engine

Hi, I am developing a car game. In it I have a player's car and an enemies car. What I want to do is, at some specific time the player's car should not collide with the enemies car. For this purpose, I want to update the maskbit of player's car at runtime. I have made custom sprite class and used this line of code to do so

```
mPhysicsWr.getPhysicsConnectorManager()
          .findBodyByShape(this)
          .getFixtureList()
          .get(0)
          .getFilterData()
          .maskBits=0;
```

but it still is not updating the maskbit of the body of this sprite.
Any idea..?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to assign the filter data again using:

```
Filter filter = new Filter();
filter.maskBits = yourMaskBits;         mPhysicsWr.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findBodyByShape(this).getFixtureList().get(0).setFilterData(filter);
```

For pretty much every Get method in Box2D there is a corresponding Set method. Its pretty unusual in the API to set properties directly. Most of the time you will use getters and setters.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please click accept on the answer so it doesn't appear in the unanswered questions for others.